# Аналог mui material UI, в React 18

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scss, react-hook, material-ui

Прочитала в документации material, что подход к созданию пользовательских стилей устарел в React 18 и получается, что он не работает. Как можно с помощью material UI создавать пользовательские стили в React 18?

```
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
    color: 'white',
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 30px',
  },
});
function App() {
const classes = useStyles;
}
```

Документация https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/

Comment: Ну стили выносите в отдельные `css` или `scss` файлы

Comment: как вариант, вы можете присмотреться через `createTheme` и `styleOverrides` задать свою общую стилистику приложения